# Running Jenkins Behind Reverse Proxy and Active Directory Authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, ldap, reverse-proxy, jenkins

I have a really weird requirement (Security team doesn't even want people who don't have access to see the Jenkins UI), where I want to run Jenkins behind reverse proxy (Apache) and then secure it via Active Directory Authentication.

Here is my config

```
LDAPCacheEntries 0
LDAPCacheTTL 5
LDAPOpCacheEntries 0
LDAPOpCacheTTL 5

<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
 ServerName localhost
 RequestHeader unset WWW-Authenticate
 ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/ retry=1 acquire=3000   timeout=600 ttl=60 Keepalive=On

ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes On

<Proxy http://localhost:8080/>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
 </Proxy>

  <Location />
  AuthLDAPBindDN “testuser”
  AuthLDAPBindPassword “testpasswd”
  AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://testserver.example.com:636/ou=test,ou=users,dc=internal,dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)"

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "AD/LDAP Credentials"
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthUserFile /dev/null
  require ldap-group     CN=Admin,OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=internal,DC=example,DC=com
  </Location>

  LogLevel debug

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/jenkins-error_log
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/jenkins-access_log common
```

Now everything looks OK, except that the page takes forever to load and sometimes I get a timeout (that's why I have the 600 sec in timeout value). So just want to confirm if there is anything wrong with my config?

Comment: Can you publish some logs from apache ? and Jenkins also maybe ?

Comment: does your linux server trust the root cert that was used to sign your ldaps connection?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but would have guessed that an AuthLDAPUrl should refer to an AD DC (or other authenticating LDAP repository), right? "TestServer" makes me think it's the site name or similar.